# Is there any evidence of naval ramming in the 9th and 10th century North Sea?

Tags: england, naval, early-medieval, netherlands, scandinavia

In Bernard Cornwell's ['Sword of the Kings'](https://books.google.ee/books?id=7ySMDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=cornwell%20sword%20of%20the%20kings&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiAzf6I7qnqAhVLPJoKHXjjB-YQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=cornwell%20sword%20of%20the%20kings&f=false), his main character uses the tactic of ramming to sink an enemy ship before engaging in hand-to-hand combat with surviving ships which get leashed together. Given that the actions take place in early 10th century England, with the main character's ship built by Frisians but sailed out of Northumbria, this sounded anachronistic to me.  **Is there any evidence of ramming as a viable naval tactic (i.e., not done out of desperation) in the North Sea of 9th and 10th centuries?**

---

The possible origins for the main character's ship may involve incorporating traditions from Scandinavia, Frisia, and Great Britain. Hence, I tried to look into the availability of ramming as a tactic in those places during this time.

### Longships

Searches [online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naval_ram) didn't come up with anything relevant for the 9th and 10th centuries, but [later Norse ships that were built for ramming (*barði*)](https://avaldsnes.info/en/viking/vikingskip/) did come up:

> A sturdy warship with a special, ironstudded prow construction **which may have been a kind of battering ram to strike enemy ships**. The word comes from barð, meaning beard/brim which denoted this particular prow.

The specific context of this seems uncertain, however, and general opinion seems to be against such uses. For example, [overviews of Medieval warfare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galley_tactics#Middle_Ages) generally describe Norse ships as poor for ramming:

> **Not built for ramming, Viking ships could not duplicate the tactics of the ancient triremes**...
> <sub>—Allfree, ['Warfare in the Medieval World'](https://books.google.ee/books?id=AeWfBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT48&lpg=PT48&dq=viking%20ships%20ramming&source=bl&ots=I3YOJG2lKu&sig=ACfU3U2pFYNKjD31X8tbe-gg3PgUpbyZGw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBrIKL66nqAhV2xMQBHUckAHAQ6AEwE3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=viking%20ships%20ramming&f=false)</sub>

Durham's 'Viking Longship' agrees with this by not mentioning ramming at all (not even in the context of the *barði* that were mentioned in the above link).

### Alfred's Navy

[Alfred's navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_the_Great#English_navy) is also generally of the opinion that ships were *not* for ship-killing but a platform on which to kill the sailors of the opponent:

> The author of the Anglo-Saxon Chronicle related that **Alfred's ships were larger, swifter, steadier and rode higher in the water than either Danish or Frisian ships**. ...
>
> Alfred had seapower in mind—if he could intercept raiding fleets before they landed, he could spare his kingdom from being ravaged. **Alfred's ships may have been superior in conception. In practice they proved to be too large to manoeuvre well in the close waters of estuaries and rivers, the only places in which a naval battle could occur.**
>
> **The warships of the time were not designed to be ship killers but rather troop carriers.** It has been suggested that, like sea battles in late Viking age Scandinavia, these battles may have entailed a ship coming alongside an enemy vessel, lashing the two ships together and then boarding the enemy craft. The result was effectively a land battle involving hand-to-hand fighting on board the two lashed vessels.

Then again, it also offers this entirely contradictory phrase:

> It is probable that, under the classical tutelage of Asser, Alfred utilised **the design of Greek and Roman warships, with high sides, designed for fighting rather than for navigation**.

And the preponderance of [ramming as a tactic in Greece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellenistic-era_warships#Oaring_system) is well known, but I'm not sure this is the intended emphasis of this paragraph (though I read it as such). Regrettably, all of Wikipedia's sources for these claims are locked for me so I cannot look for them in the original sources.

So, is there any evidence?